# How to set cellpadding and cellspacing in table with CSS?

Tags: html, css

Can someone tell me how to change table cellpadding and cellspacing like you can do it in html with:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
```

But how is it done with css?

Answer (score 43):

Use `padding` on the cells and `border-spacing` on the table. The former will give you cellpadding while the latter will give you cellspacing.

```
table { border-spacing: 5px; } /* cellspacing */

th, td { padding: 5px; } /* cellpadding */
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eRVHQ/1/)

Comment: Update: added a demo that better illustrates stuff

Answer (score 14):

The padding inside a table-divider (TD) is a padding property applied to the cell itself.

CSS

```
td, th {padding:0}
```

The spacing in-between the table-dividers is a space between cell borders of the TABLE. To make it effective, you have to specify if your table cells borders will 'collapse' or be 'separated'.

CSS

```
table, td, th {border-collapse:separate}
table {border-spacing:6px}
```

Try this : https://www.google.ca/search?num=100&newwindow=1&q=css+table+cellspacing+cellpadding+site%3Astackoverflow.com ( 27 100 results )

Comment: border-collapse:separated is invalid.  Should be separate (no 'd')

Answer (score 5):

Here is the [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/mVSaa/1/).

The HTML:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            123
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The CSS:

```
table { 
      border-spacing:0; 
      border-collapse:collapse;   
    }
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

```
td, th {padding:0}
```

Comment: Cell spacing and padding are attributes of the cells inside the table. I would think that setting the margin and padding on the td would be more accurate.

Comment: here is the fiddle for the same http://jsfiddle.net/mVSaa/ - @Darkwater23

Comment: I agree to your point. Tried, tested and finally edited the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/mVSaa/1/ - @Darkwater23